# What this mean in vb Do '' Bgw1 = Backgroundworker1 ? And how to convert it to csharp?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, vb.net-to-c#

In my form1 designer i have only one backgroundworker name: Bgw1 but i don't have backgroundworker1 not in the designer and not in the code.

```
Do       '' Bgw1 = Backgroundworker1
            If Bgw1.CancellationPending Then ' Have we pressed Cancel?
                Exit Sub
```

Comment: It seems it's part of a [`Do-Loop`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eked04a7.aspx) statement and the C# equivalent is a [`do-while`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/370s1zax.aspx) statement. Also `'` is vb comment symbol which its C# equivalent is `//`. And instead of vb `Exit Sub` you can use `return` in C#.

Comment: So not converting to c# only the line Bgw1 = Backgroundworker1 or also the IF and the Exist ? What i did now in c# is: if (Bgw1.CancellationPending)
            {
                return;
            }

Comment: Yes, this is what you need.

Comment: You can convert between C# and VB.NET using online tools like [this](http://developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb) or [this one](http://codeconverter.sharpdevelop.net/SnippetConverter.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In visual basic, the `'` character begins a comment.  In C#, comments begin with `//`.

In this case, you're probably better off not converting it to C#, since it seems to be misleading.